# HTTP Session Management while using Nginx as in "Round Robin" mode Load-balancer?

Tags: session, nginx, load-balancing, round-robin

I'm trying to load-balance "2 Web Servers (running Apache/PHP)" by putting `Nginx` at in front of them. But **I need to use Round Robin algorithm** but when i do this, **I can't manage to have the stable SESSIONS**.

(I understand; if I use Round Robin, the SESSION information will be lost once i hit to the another Server on next load)

Is there a proper way to achieve this? Any kind advice for the industrial standards on this please?

*FYI, I have already put these 2 Web Servers into `GlusterFS` as in Cluster. So I have a common storage (if you are going to suggest something based on this)*

Answer (score 1):

The nginx manual says that session affinity is in the commercial distribution only ("sticky" directive).  If you don't use the commercial distribution, you'll have to grab a third-party "plugin" and rebuild the server with support

("sticky" should help you find the third party addons)

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation =) Can you please let me know which particular "plugin" or module should i use pls?

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any specific reason for using `Round Robin`, you can try to use `ip_hash` load balancing mechanism.

```
upstream myapp1 {
    ip_hash;
    server srv1.example.com;
    server srv2.example.com;
    server srv3.example.com;
}
```

> If there is the need to tie a client to a particular application server — in other words, make the client’s session “sticky” or “persistent” in terms of always trying to select a particular server — the ip-hash load balancing mechanism can be used.

Please refer to [nginx doc for load_balancing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_load_balancing_with_ip_hash) for more information.